# Curl | How to decode json?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to get some info from the json,

How can i get it please?

curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: ***"));

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$values = json_decode($html);
$info = $values['a']['new'];
echo "$info";
```

The json:

```
{"a":{"new":"someinfo..."}}
```

I try to get what is inside ['a']['new'];

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` [More Info](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

for your json

```
{"a":{"new":"someinfo..."}}
```

User jq command

```
$ jq '.a.new'
> "someinfo..."
```